# RegEx: How to find all newline symbols not preceded by a double quote?

Tags: regex, csv, perl

I want to remove all illegal newline symbols LF in a CSV file between double quotes.

```
"name", "created"
"David A","2022-04-04"
"Mark
B", "2022-04-09"
"Peter C", "2022-05-01"
```

The file is called `name.csv` for example

Now I can do it with

```sh
cat name.csv |
| perl -p -e 's/\n/!LF_SYMBOL!/g'        \
| perl -p -e 's/"!LF_SYMBOL!"/"!EOL!"/g' \
| perl -p -e 's/!LF_SYMBOL!//g'          \
| perl -p -e 's/!EOL!/\n/g'              \
> name_new.csv
```

But it's ugly. I want to remove all newlines not following a double quote

I have tried

```sh
perl -p -e 's/[^"]\n//' name.csv
```

and

```sh
perl -p -e 's/^[^"]\n//' name.csv
```

Both just removing all `"\n` for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some commas are missing there for this to be a valid CSV.  Is that by typo?  Do you have a valid CSV (with newlines in fields) or not?

Comment: Use `perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")\s*,\s*(?1)$/$&=~s!\R+!!gr/gme' file`

Comment: It's actually the spaces after the commas that make this illegal CSV

Comment: Embedded newlines are not illegal in csv, are they? What is the reason you need to remove these newlines?

Comment: Sorry I just made up an simple example as the real csv I handle is very large with many fields and rows. If some commas are missing, it's my typo. But the problem I encounter is the same : I need to remove the :Linux format end-of-line symbol (LF) between double quotes but not affecting the ones in the row end.  This file comes everyday to be fed in IBM DataStage sequential stage for auto processing and load data to database.  The Stage treats each LF symbol as row end and skips the rows having this problem. I want to add a stage to 'clean' the CSV files before feeding it to sequential stage.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually best to use an existing parser rather than writing your own. This is no exception.

[Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) has no problem handling line feeds in double-quoted fields.<sup>[1]</sup>

It can even tolerate the whitespace after the comma if `allow_whitespace => 1` is provided.

So I would use this module rather than writing my own parser.

All you need is this:

```sh
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e'
   csv
      in => *ARGV,
      allow_whitespace => 1,
      on_in => sub { s/\n//g for @{ $_[1] }; };
' name.csv >name_new.csv
```

Output:

```
name,created
"David A",2022-04-04
MarkB,2022-04-09
"Peter C",2022-05-01
```

If for some reason you want to avoid XS, the slower Text::CSV is a drop-in replacement.

---

1. Handling line feeds in fields require passing `binary => 1`, which is the default when using the `csv` function.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a valid CSV file read it using a library, like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).  They don't have a problem with newlines embedded  in fields and then it's simple to remove those

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file.csv\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new(
    { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, allow_whitespace => 1 }); 

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
    s/\n+//g for @$row; 
    $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

This can be done in a one-liner as well, if there is some benefit to that.

---

The posted text, as it stands, isn't valid CSV and cannot be directly parsed by a library since commas are missing between fields.  I presume that those are typos since the question says "CSV" at multiple places.  Please clarify.

The embedded newlines are accepted with the `binary` attribute while the extras spaces after commas (strictly invalid) are accepted with the `allow_whitespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a two-column "CSV"-like file and all you want is to remove line breaks inside the two fields, you can use a solution like

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")\s*,\s*(?1)$/$&=~s!\R+!!gr/gme' file.csv
```

See the [main regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZVf0q/1). When the match is found, the second regex, `s!\R+!!gr` removes all line breaks inside the match.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")` - Group 1: `"`, zero or more chars other than `"`, then zero or more repetitions of `""` and then zero or more chars other than `"`, and then a `"` (matches a CSV field where literal double quotes are escaped with `"`)
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(?1)` - a subroutine that repeats Group 1 pattern
- `$` - end of a line (due to `m` flag).

Comment: perl -i -pe 's/^("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")\s*,\s*(?1)$/$&=~s!\R+!!gr/gme' name.csv
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s!\R+!!gr"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s!\R+!!gr "
Sequence (?1...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/("[^"]*(?:""["]*)*")\s*,\s*(?1 <-- HERE )$/ at -e line 1.

Comment: @RickyHope No idea what you mean, ***my*** solution [**works well**](https://ideone.com/hv2jSD).