# I am in troubles with a regexp to remove some \n

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

Im trying to define a regexp to remove some carriage return in a file to be loaded into a DB.

Here is the fragment

```
200;GBP;;"";"";"";"";;;;"";"";"";"";;;"";1122;"BP JET WASH IP2 9RP
";"";Hamilton;"";;0;0;0;1;1;"";
```

This is the regexp I used in https://regex101.com/

```
(;"[[:alnum:] ]+)[\n]+([[:alnum:] ]*)"
```

Which should get two groups, one before and one after some newline.

Looking at regexp101, it informs that the groups are correctly captured

[image]

But the result is wrong, because it still introduce an invisible new line as follow

[image]

I also try to use `sed` but the result is exactly the same.

So, the question is: Where am I wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72102596/589924

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix replace new lines inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026137/unix-replace-new-lines-inside-quotes)

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150640/how-to-remove-new-lines-within-double-quotes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406281/replace-new-line-character-between-double-quotes-with-space)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is line based. It's possible to achieve what you want, but I'd rather use a more suitable tool. For example, Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/<>/e if tr/"// % 2 == 1' file.csv
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line before outputting it;
- The `/e` option interprets the replacement in a substitution as code, in this case replacing the final newline with the following line (`<>` reads the input)
- `tr/"//` in numeric context returns the number of matches, i.e. the number of double quotes;
- If the number is odd, we remove the newline (`%` is the modulo operator).

The corresponding `sed` invocation would be

```
sed '/^\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*"[^"]*$/{N;s/\n//}' file.csv
```

- on lines containing a non-paired double quote, read the next line to the pattern space (`N`) and remove the newline.

### Update:

```
perl -ne 'chomp $p if ! /^[0-9]+;/; print $p; $p = $_; END { print $p }' file.csv
```

This should remove the newlines if they're not followed by a number and a semicolon. It keeps the *previous line* in the variable `$p`, if the current line doesn't start with a number followed by a semicolon, newline is [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp)ed from the previous line. The, the previous line is printed and the current line is remembered. The last line needs to be printed separately as there's no following line for it to make it printed.

Comment: No, it doesn't run. I have multiple lines, and your perl broken the file. For example I have `sfully.;133920765814;XZZ64b49c844353cE47C7V7UEKERFFYB;;2021-12-05 14:02:48;64499;2;;1843;1;;;;;;;2021-12-05 14:02:50.524693;frontend-01;""220;GBP;`. If you look at the end, the `220;GBP` was the start of a new line!

Comment: That's quite different to what you showed - almost no double quotes!

Comment: @choroba there are a billion of lines. each one starts with a number,a semicolon, and a currency like "200;EUR"
If a line ends with a \n and it is not followed by a number and a semicolon, the newline must be removed. What is after the newline must be preserved.

Comment: What about `perl -ne 'chomp $p if ! /^[0-9]+;/; print $p; $p = $_; END { print $p }'` then?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -wE'csv(in=>csv(in=>shift,sep=>";",on_in=>sub{s/\n+$// for@{$_[1]}}))' file.csv
```

will remove trailing newlines from every field in the CSV (with sep `;`) and spit out correct CSV (with sep `,`). If you want `;` in to output too, use

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -wE'csv(in=>csv(in=>shift,sep=>";",on_in=>sub{s/\n+$// for@{$_[1]}}),sep=>";")' file.csv
```

Comment: Your solution convert empty strings to NULL, and it's overly complex to use two calls to `csv`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72113950/589924)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to use an existing parser rather than writing your own.

I'd use the following Perl program:

```sh
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e'
   csv
      in             => *ARGV,
      sep            => ";",
      blank_is_undef => 1,
      quote_empty    => 1,
      on_in          => sub { s/\n//g for @{ $_[1] }; };
' old.csv >new.csv
```

Output:

```
200;GBP;;"";"";"";"";;;;"";"";"";"";;;"";1122;"BP JET WASH IP2 9RP";"";Hamilton;"";;0;0;0;1;1;"";
```

If for some reason you want to avoid XS, the slower Text::CSV is a drop-in replacement.